# Void $.post() function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, chat

I have a chat application that calls `$.post()` each couple of seconds.

```
var currentPage = "chat-room-1";
var myJSONString = null;

$.post("getJSON.php?view_page=currentPage", function(response) {
    myJSONstring += response; 
});
```

Every `$.post()` returns and adds whatever new entries are found in the database for my current chatroom.

Each time `currentPage` variable changes I set `myJSONstring` to `null` (I go to another chatroom)

Problem occurs when I change my `currentPage` variable while the `$.post()` is being processed but hasn't returned a value yet, because server takes longer time to process it.
This creates an instance that old chatroom data and new chatroom data are both added to  `myJSONstring`.

Solution I can see is that at any time I change `currentPage` I also void any `$.post()` functions that haven't returned a value yet. Is that possible?

Comment: Not the issue, but: You cannot concat JSON strings, and you cannot concat them with `null`. Use an array `[]`, and push the parsed results from the response to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can abort a ajax request like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("getJSON.php?view_page=currentPage", function(response) {
    myJSONstring += response; 
});

jqxhr.abort();
```

but not sure if it's 100% reliable in your case.

an other solution could be to put your chat content in an array. And return the current page in your server answer.

```
var currentPage = "chat-room-1";
var chatRoomStr = [];
chatRoomStr[currentPage] = '';

$.post("getJSON.php?view_page=currentPage", function(response) {
    chatRoomStr[response.currentPage] += response.chatContent; 
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to set those vars to empty strings in order to be able to concat.

Answer (score 0):

Scope ajax calling with a [IIFE function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and ignore response if the chatroom has changed.

```
var currentPage = "chat-room-1";
var myJSONString = null;

(function(chatRoom) {
    $.post("getJSON.php?view_page=" + chatRoom, function(response) {
        if (chatRoom == currentPage) {
            myJSONstring += response; 
        }
    }); 
})(currentPage);
```

PS: I copied your code in my response. But you should heed to @Bergi's advice (+1).